# spark udf not being called

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Given the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val testUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((a: String, b: String, c: Int) => { 
  val out = s"test1: $a $b $c"
  println(out)
  out
})

val testUdf2: UserDefinedFunction = udf((a: String, b: String, c: String) => { 
  val out = s"test2: $a $b $c"
  println(out)
  out
})

Seq(("hello", "world", null))
.toDF("a", "b", "c")
.withColumn("c", $"c" cast "Int")
.withColumn("test1", testUdf($"a", $"b", $"c"))
.withColumn("test2", testUdf2($"a", $"b", $"c"))
.show
```

`testUdf` does not appear to be called. There is no error, no warning, it just returns null.

Is there a way to detect these silent failures? Also, what is going on here?

Spark 2.4.4
Scala 2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what caused this. But I think it is most likely because of the implicit conversion

**code1**

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val testUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((a: String, b: String, c: Int) => {
      val out = s"test1: $a $b $c"
      println(out)
      out
    })
    
    Seq(("hello", "world", null))
      .toDF("a", "b", "c")
      .withColumn("test1", testUdf($"a", $"b", $"c"))
      .show
```

**code2**

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val testUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((a: String, b: String, c: String) => {
      val out = s"test1: $a $b $c"
      println(out)
      out
    })

    Seq(("hello", "world", null))
      .toDF("a", "b", "c")
      .withColumn("test1", testUdf($"a", $"b", $"c"))
      .show
```

**code1 logical plan**

[image]

**code2 logical plan**

[image: code2 logical plan]

Comment: The case 1 logical plan explains what is going on quite well. It is a bit unexpected, but, at least I know what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Scala type "Int" does not allow nulls. Variable "c" type can be changed to "Integer".

Comment: Thank you for this answer, +1. I was really trying to understand why the function was not called at all, which was shown in the answer by yangzhongbao

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `scala.MatchError: scala.Null` error when you try to cast to null, besides your definition of UDF doesn't work for me as I got a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type AnyRef is not supported` when I try to register it.

What about this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def testUdf(a: String, b: String, c: Integer): String = { 
  val out = s"test1: $a $b $c"
  println(out)
  out
}

def testUdf2(a: String, b: String, c: String): String = { 
  val out = s"test2: $a $b $c"
  println(out)
  out
}

val yourTestUDF = udf(testUdf _)
val yourTestUDF2 = udf(testUdf2 _)

// spark.udf.register("yourTestUDF", yourTestUDF) // just in case you need it in SQL

spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("hello", "world", null.asInstanceOf[Integer])))
.toDF("a", "b", "c")
.withColumn("test1", yourTestUDF($"a", $"b", $"c"))
.withColumn("test2", yourTestUDF2($"a", $"b", $"c"))
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
test1: hello world null
test2: hello world null
+-----+-----+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|a    |b    |c   |test1                  |test2                  |
+-----+-----+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|hello|world|null|test1: hello world null|test2: hello world null|
+-----+-----+----+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```